# Is the Insights add-in breaking the rules?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Have just loaded the Insights add-in and, assuming this is an office add-in, isn't it breaking one of the main rules? The data being displayed is not related to the current email, its a dashboard, and remains constant when changing the current item. I would love to do this with my add-in but its my understanding I wouldn't be able to get it in the app store.

Comment: Sorry, but: which rules? Please edit your question. Explain what you would expect to see. Describe what you see instead. Then explain you reason why you would like to see the expected.

Comment: When I search for "Insights" in [AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/?search=Insights), I get a lot of hits. Can you specify the full official name of the add-in?

Comment: @Boris Could the "Insights" add-in you are talking about be an internal add-in in your company? If it is not deployed through AppSource, it is not subject to the AppSource rules. For example, in Microsoft we have an internal add-in named "Insights" which also does not display data related to the current email.

Comment: Adding here instead of answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a requirement for add-ins that support pinning only
4.12.1 If your add-in manifest includes the SupportsPinning element for read mode of a message and/or appointment, the content of the add-in, when pinned, must not be static and must clearly display data related to the message that is open or selected in the mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is, indeed,  the Microsoft Insights add-in that i'm referring to. We are desperately trying to find ways of replacing our VSTO add-in with a new add-in and one of the things we need to do is add a dashboard so when I saw Insights was doing it I got very jealous.

Comment: So, dare I ask, why  apps deployed through AppSource must display data related to the current email?

Comment: Boris, apologies for the delay in response. We find add-ins add the most value when they enable our Outlook users to be more productive by bringing in external content and services in the context of their current task at hand which can be an email or a meeting request. Insights Outlook add-in is an extension of Microsoft MyAnalytics product, and is part of our strategy to make end users be more productive.

Comment: We do believe that our partners can benefit from enabling add-ins to run outside the context of an item and that will allow some interesting scenarios. However that requires us to do additional work on the platform and will need to be prioritized. This feature has been requested by other partners as well and is part of our backlog. We use user voice to track customer/ partner requests. You are welcome to up-vote the existing feature request. Number of up-votes on a feature request, on user voice, is one of the inputs to our quarterly planning process.

Comment: Here is the link to the existing feature request you can use to up-vote

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/11378751-provide-an-option-to-make-outlook-add-ins-command

Comment: Thank you for the update; I will do the up-vote and hope it gets actioned!